# Using jQuery to process a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, data-structures

My JSON object is constructed like this:

```
var Source =
{
    Object: [ //Array
        {Title: 'Test', Type: 'Pet', Category: 'Cat', Description: 'Fluffy', Count: 2 }
    ]
};
```

I was able to figure out how to properly add to the 'Object' array, but I can't seem to figure out the jQuery syntax to query the object based on the property list (Title, Type, Category, etc).

I put some test code into a click event and normally check the length of the Source.Object (Test data results in 2 objects) to confirm that there is data to work with (It's populated through an ajax call).

```
function clickTest(category, type) {
    $(Source).find('Object[Category=\"' + category + '\"]').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('Category')); //doesn't work
    });
}
```

What is the right way to query a JSON object like this?

Comment: I have to say, wtf?

Comment: Sorry man, what did I do wrong here?

Comment: @C Bauer: What is it you are trying to do? Do you want to query a JavaScript Object with CSS-selectors? CSS-selectors and most of jQuery's methods are meant to be used on the DOM.

Comment: @CBauer: the whole thing I guess. I'm not even sure what you're trying to achieve here. You have a plain `javascript object`, which you **could** just access in a way like `Source.Object.Category` (the name `Object` is probably a bad idea btw since it's a reserved word), but you're trying to pull that object into a jQuery constructor to get what? A jQuery object from a javascript object?

Comment: @elusive - I knew that, but I thought that JSON was one of the supported data structures that jQuery can be used on. I used jQuery to traverse the XML structures that make up the data here.
@jAndy - I need to be able to query for a large number of possible objects and pull up only the ones that match certain criteria, the click function is an example. I need category of 'Pet' and type 'Cat', or I need 'Utensils' and 'Fork', or just 'Utensils'.

Comment: @C Bauer: XML is represented using DOM (which can be seen as a huge collection of various JavaScript objects). JSON represents a plain JavaScript object without any kind of selector-support or events. You do not need selectors for this. You can access properties of an object by using the `.`-operator.

Comment: @elusive - Thanks for the help. I thought jQuery could do everything I guess :)

Comment: @C Bauer: Why should jQuery do something that is natively supported by the language? This reminds me of the [jQuery Basic Arithmetic Plugin](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/buosj/add_a_number_to_another_number_in_javascript_img/c0on5ev) ;)

Comment: @C Bauer: everything except this! jk :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON is native to JavaScript and can be cycled through without the use of libraries (jQuery). The `[]` represent arrays, and `{}` represent objects, therefore:

```
var obj = Source.Object;
for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (obj[i].Category == category)
        alert(obj[i].Category + ' ' + obj[i].Title);
}
```

And that's faster, too! Good stuff.

Comment: I'd always assumed that jQuery would be faster then building a javascript loop to make these checks.

Comment: @C Bauer: jQuery would be shorter. Pure JavaScript will be faster (since the closures call variables from other scope, etc.) After all, jQuery is written in JavaScript -- calling it won't always beat a custom solution.

Answer (score 5):

The source is a JSON object, not a HTML DOM. Therefore, you must use the jQuery utility functions for arrays:

```
$.grep( Source.Object, function(e) { return e.Category == category } ).each(...)
```

Comment: "must" sounds rather extreme, no? :)

Comment: +1 - the rare (mostly) proper use of `$.grep()`, the `.each()` after will blow up though, it should be wrapped in a `$.each(...)`, since `.grep()` returns an array.

Comment: I would correct: "you _can_ use the jQuery utility functions" - they're not necessary as that's just plain JavaScript.

Comment: nice, i didn't know $.grep(object, function) but it's good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

JSon is a way to transcribe a javascript object in a string format and transmit it on the wire. One nice thing about the format is that it's directly readable by javascript, so your Source object is already ready to be processed.

```
function processSource(source, category)
{
    var counter = 0;
    for (counter = 0; counter < source.Object.length; counter += 1)
    {
        if (category === source.Object[counter].category) {
           // do something
        }
    }
}
```